# Android GridLayout Row index

Tags: android, checkbox, toast, grid-layout

I have a design Layout like the code below,and I want to write a code for each checkbox to show me the index of the selected row when checked ,but I don't know how to fetch this property from my gridlayout dynamically and not by typing the index manually in the Toast.makeText().I'll be grateful if you help me on this issue.

Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:columnCount="5"
  android:rowCount="4" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:background="#FF1354"
  android:id="@+id/Grd">
  <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 1 " 
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView 
      android:text=" R 1, C 2 "
       android:background="@drawable/border"/>

  <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 3 "
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 4 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/chk1"
      android:text=""
     style="?android:attr/starStyle"  />

  <TextView android:text=" R 2, C 1 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 2, C 2 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 2, C 3 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 2, C 4 "
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/chk2"
       android:text=""
   style="?android:attr/starStyle"  />

  <TextView android:text=" R 3, C 1 "
       android:background="@drawable/border" />
  <TextView android:text=" R 3, C 2 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 3, C 3 "
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 3, C 4 " 
      android:background="@drawable/border"/>

  <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/chk3"
      android:text=""
       style="?android:attr/starStyle"/>

  <TextView android:text=" R 4, C 1 "
    android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 4, C 2 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 4, C 3 "
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 4, C 4 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/chk4"
      android:text=""
      style="?android:attr/starStyle" />

</GridLayout>
```

and Here is my code:

```
package com.example.hiiiiiiiiiiiiii;

import com.example.mynewtestoftablecheck.MyNewTestTableCheck;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii);


      CheckBox chk1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk1);
      chk1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          GridLayout Grd=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.Grd);


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            {
                if (((CheckBox) arg0).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii.this,
                               "1st Row checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii.this,
                            "1st Row Unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
                }

            }
        });



      CheckBox chk2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk2);
      CheckBox chk3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk3);
      CheckBox chk4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk4);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:columnCount="5"
  android:rowCount="4" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:background="#FF1354"
  android:id="@+id/Grd">
</GridLayout>
```

separately item_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 1 " 
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView 
      android:text=" R 1, C 2 "
       android:background="@drawable/border"/>

  <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 3 "
       android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 4 "
      android:background="@drawable/border" />

  <CheckBox 
      android:id="@+id/chk1"
      android:text=""
     style="?android:attr/starStyle"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

and next you custom grig adapter

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList;

    public GridviewAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mapList_) {
        super();
        this.mapList = mapList_;
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mapList.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);



            convertView.setTag(view);
        } else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        view.txtViewTitle.setText("NAME");


        return convertView;
    }
```

in you activity

```
adapter = new GridviewAdapter(this, mapList);
        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMain);
        gridView.setNumColumns(GridviewAdapter.rowCount);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
        // gridView.setColumnWidth(GridviewAdapter.returnDisplayMetrics(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {



            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks,but I don't have any imageview !would you plz explain the gridadpater that you've written

Comment: sorry image view is really missing :) I inflated the base adapter... 1 minute i add sorce

Comment: Sorry but I get too many errors on non-implemented classes or methods or undefined variables,like the following:                               The method initializeDisplayMetrics() is undefined for the type GridviewAdapter

Comment: Thanks a lot,but give me hint plz to solve these two last errors                     

The type GridviewAdapter must implement the inherited abstract method Adapter.getItem(int)


myImageViewText cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: <TextView android:text=" R 1, C 1 "   android:id="@+id/myImageViewText" 
       android:background="@drawable/border" />